# Using array to store the names of the workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code which stores the names of the excel workbooks in an 
  array and I am using it into a for loop.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myArr  As Variant
Dim lngCounter  As Long

myArr = Array("Rahul", "Ameya")

For lngCounter = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\New folder\" & 
myArr(lngCounter) & ".xls")

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ND18521\Desktop\New folder\" & 
myArr(lngCounter) & ".xls")

With x.Sheets(myArr(lngCounter))
Set aCell1 = .Range("A1:X1000").Find(What:="User", LookIn:=xlValues, 
LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
 .Range(aCell1, .Cells(.Rows.Count, aCell1.Column).End(xlUp)).Offset(2, 
  0).Copy _
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(myArr(lngCounter)).Range("A2")
  End With

Next lngCounter
End Sub
```

But I am getting error on the below line :

**With x.Sheets(myArr(lngCounter))**

Error : Object required

Comment: remove the `"`s

Comment: even then it doesnot work

Comment: What is the error when the quotes are removed?

Comment: Do you really have a sheet named the same as the workbook name?

Comment: yes.
Name of the workbook as well as the name of the sheet is Rahul
and i have stored that in an arryay
it is working for this line :
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\New folder\" & 
myArr(lngCounter) & ".xls")
But not for :
With x.Sheets("myArr(lngCounter)")

Comment: What is the error? not on which line.

Comment: Runtime error '424' 
Object required

Comment: Take a look at my answer of your previous question once again - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838527/using-array-instead-of-different-subs-in-vba  and try to adapt it. I have no `"` there.

Comment: Hey vityata.
Thanx for your answer. Really appreciate your help
I am not getting how to use that.
i have removed the quotes, bt still getting the error. Please help :(

Comment: Put your code again in the question with the removed quotes, @AnirudhChauhan

Comment: you don't define `x` or `y`

Comment: Shouldn't `Dim myArr  As Variant` be `Dim myArr()  As Variant`?

Comment: @dwirony : you are right brother..but still getting the same issue

Comment: you arent literally using `"C:\Users\*****"` are you?

Comment: @AnirudhChauhan I want to retract my comment - since the array is not a `String`, the () are not needed-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use code from StackOverflow, try to understand what is staying behind it. [Or at least use the same indentation as in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838527/using-array-instead-of-different-subs-in-vba). Having said this, try the following

1. Create two files - `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` on your desktop.
2. Run the following code.
3. Try to adapt it.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myArr           As Variant
    Dim myWb            As Workbook
    Dim lngCounter      As Long

    myArr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

    For lngCounter = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)

        Set myWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\" _
                                              & myArr(lngCounter) & ".xlsx")

        With myWb.Worksheets(myArr(lngCounter))
            Debug.Print .Name
        End With

        myWb.Close False

    Next lngCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: The user's name is "Desktop" ?

Comment: @braX - it could be that in the Users folder there is another folder named Desktop.

Comment: True, albeit highly unlikely, and the OP is just going to say "it doesnt work" :P

Comment: @braX - I know what you mean, fixed it.

Comment: Even i was doing the same but  i was adding some stupid lines too in the code.
Thanx for ur help vityata and sorry for the trouble caused.

Comment: @AnirudhChauhan - its not trouble, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `x.Worksheets(myArr(lngCounter))`

Comment: It's really strange because the error "object required" seems indicate that the x is not set.. 

If you put a stop point just after setting the x workbook did you see the x workbook ?
I guess it should put an error before but .. let's try.
And just to verify, did you close x later or it's alwways opened? Beacause it could be an error like "The workbook it's already open..blahblah"..

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues with the code, but my main concern is that you are looping over an array that holds filenames, but in the same moment you use these names as sheet names. Is this really what you want to do? Does the workbook `Rahul` has a worksheet `Rahul` and the workbook `Ameya` has a sheet `Ameya`?

Other things to mention:

- You never use the workbook you assign to `y`
- You don't declare variables x and y. Always use `option explicit` and
  declare all variables to avoid difficult to find bugs.